# Extending a Hungarian student visa

Tags: schengen, visa-extensions, hungary

I have a student visa issued by the Hungarian embassy, but my passport expires before my education period, so I have to renew my passport and my student visa. I also have a residence permit and have been in Hungary for about 6 months now. How am I going to extend the visa considering I have the required documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [web site dedicated to Schengen area visas](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/) suggests that to renew a visa while in the Schengen area you should apply through the immigration service of the country in which you're currently resident. Unfortunately, they don't give much information on where or who that is for any given country.

However, a search through the Hungarian Government web site lists this entry for Consular Services under [Ministry of Foreign Affairs and Trade](http://www.kormany.hu/en/ministry-of-foreign-affairs-and-trade/contacts):

> Consular Service
>
> Postal address: 1027 Budapest, Nagy Imre tér 4.
>
> Phone: 458-1000
>
> Fax: 201-7323
>
> E-mail: konz@mfa.gov.hu;
>
> taj.konz@mfa.gov.hu

They should be able to answer your questions. Give them a call!

Comment: Thanx a ton mate!